# Localizar el texto de un nodo a través de su hermano anterior

Tags: xpath

A ver si me podéis ayudar, que ya he probado de todo y no soy capaz.

```
<div class="product-specifications-row">
    <div class="product-specifications-cell">
        <span class="product-specifications-label">Usage:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-specifications-value">
        <span>Summer tyre</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero buscar es el texto "usage:" y si lo encuentra que me muestre el valor del span del siguiente div.
la primera parte la tengo con esto: //span[contains(., 'Usage:')]
Pero luego ya no se como saltar al span del siguiente div
Lo he intentado durante varias horas y es que ya no que mas probar

Answer (score 1):

### solución

`//div[span/contains(., 'Usage:')]/following-sibling::div/span/node()`

#### traducción

- selecciono el nodo div que tiene como hijo un span que contiene como texto Usage:
- hago un following-sibliding ( siguiente nodo del que comparto padre/madre)
- entro en el div/span y saco el texto

Puedes comprobar y jugar en : http://xpather.com/2eKFtTHP